# how does macro-generating macro work in clojure

Tags: clojure, macros

Here is a macro-generating macro I learned from #clojure channel:

```
(defmacro import-alias
  [new-name imported]
  `(defmacro ~new-name [f# & body#]
     `(. ~'~imported ~f# ~@body#)))
(pprint 
  (macroexpand-1 
    '(import-alias J Math)))
```

This expands to:

```
(clojure.core/defmacro
 J
 [f__36239__auto__ & body__36240__auto__]
 (clojure.core/seq
  (clojure.core/concat
   (clojure.core/list '.)
   (clojure.core/list 'Math)
   (clojure.core/list f__36239__auto__)
   body__36240__auto__)))
```

How come we get single-element lists concatenated together? I know this is very tricky wizardry and I wouldn't do it in practice, but I am intrigued nonetheless, how does it actually work?

If I just change the position of one quote, then the expansion is quite different:

```
(defmacro import-alias
  [new-name imported]
  `(defmacro ~new-name [f# & body#]
     `(. ~~'imported ~f# ~@body#)))
(pprint
  (macroexpand-1
    '(import-alias J Math)))

;;; expand:
(clojure.core/defmacro
 J
 [f__36269__auto__ & body__36270__auto__]
 (clojure.core/seq
  (clojure.core/concat
   (clojure.core/list '.)
   (clojure.core/list imported)
   (clojure.core/list f__36269__auto__)
   body__36270__auto__)))
```

and:

```
(defmacro import-alias
  [new-name imported]
  `(defmacro ~new-name [f# & body#]
     `(. '~~imported ~f# ~@body#)))
(pprint
  (macroexpand-1
    '(import-alias J Math)))

;; expand:
(clojure.core/defmacro
 J
 [f__36323__auto__ & body__36324__auto__]
 (clojure.core/seq
  (clojure.core/concat
   (clojure.core/list '.)
   (clojure.core/list
    (clojure.core/seq
     (clojure.core/concat
      (clojure.core/list 'quote)
      (clojure.core/list Math))))
   (clojure.core/list f__36323__auto__)
   body__36324__auto__)))
```

Why?

Comment: Have you read [about reader macro characters](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters) ?